# Vertical scroll increases after text rotation inside table in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I was trying to  create a tabular structure using html/ css where som eof my texts are aligned vertically. The code at https://jsfiddle.net/souviiik/35xbre76/ demostrates the output. I am facing a blank vertical scroll even after the table is complete.

if you comment out style rules at line #1119, #1268 and #1307 in the CSS the vertical scroll works fine. The code that is causing the issue is as below,

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-315px, 0);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-315px, 0);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-315px, 0);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-315px, 0);
transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-315px, 0);
```

Comment: There is a `table caption` -  `.nextGenHiddenFieldWindow { left: -10000px;` wich somehow give the scroll.

Comment: -10,000px is creating a vertical indent after the text-transform, resulting that extra space after the table ends. Thanks for the hint. :)